# Merge multiple lines with non null values in Redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I would like to obtain one line only that contains the non null values from the table that can be reproduced from the following code:

```
select
  1 as unique_id,
  'null' as first,
  'second' as second,
  'null' as third
union all
select
  1 as unique_id,
  'first' as first,
  'null' as second,
  'null' as third
union all
select
  1 as unique_id,
  'null' as first,
  'null' as second,
  'third' as third
```

Comment: Please, provide expected output. Shouldn't there be just NULL instead of 'NULL' - this is text, not the empty value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of your supplied code (assuming 'null' should be NULL) is:

```
1, 'first', NULL, NULL
1, NULL, 'second', NULL
1, NULL, NULL, 'third'
```

By 'merge', I assume you want output that looks like:

```
1, 'first', 'second', 'third'
```

This could be done with:

```
SELECT MAX(first), MAX(second), MAX(third) FROM ... GROUP BY unique_id
```

Of course, this assumes you only have each value appearing once per `unique_id`. You could similarly use other functions such as `MIN` or `LISTAGG` -- they simply have to be something that excludes NULL values.